# Compare two text files line by line, finding differences but ignoring numerical values differences

Tags: bash, awk

I'm working on a bash script to compare two similar text files line by line and find the eventual differences between each line of the files, I should point the difference and tell in which line the difference is, but I should ignore the numerical values in this comparison.

Example:

```
Process is running; process found : 12603 process is listening on port 1200
Process is running; process found : 43023 process is listening on port 1200
```

In the example above, the script shouldn't find any difference since it's just the process id and it changes all the time.

But otherwise I want it to notify me of the differences between the lines.

Example:

```
Process is running; process found : 12603 process is listening on port 1200
Process is not running; process found : 43023 process is not listening on port 1200
```

I already have a working script to find the differences, and i've used the following function to find the difference and ignore the numerical values, but it's not working perfectly, Any suggestions ?

```
    COMPARE_FILES()
{
    awk 'NR==FNR{a[FNR]=$0;next}$0!~a[FNR]{print $0}' $1 $2
}
```

Where `$1` and `$2` are the two files to compare.

Comment: What is the supposed result, if one line contains `foo77bar baz` and the other line contains `foo78bar baz`? Are they considered equal or different?

Comment: _it's not working perfectly_ : This means it is nearly working. Therefore, you should publish one concrete case, where your algorithm produces a different result from what you expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would you please try the following:

```
COMPARE_FILES() {
    awk '
    NR==FNR {a[FNR]=$0; next}
    {
        b=$0; gsub(/[0-9]+/,"",b)
        c=a[FNR]; gsub(/[0-9]+/,"",c)
        if (b != c) {printf "< %s\n> %s\n", $0, a[FNR]}
    }' "$1" "$2"
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the prompt feedback. If you consider your problem is well solved with my answer, I'd appreciate if you can accept it by clicking on the check mark beside the answer. BR.

Answer (score 0):

> Any suggestions ?

Jettison digits before making comparison, I would ameloriate your code following way replace

```
NR==FNR{a[FNR]=$0;next}$0!~a[FNR]{print $0}
```

using

```
NR==FNR{a[FNR]=$0;next}gensub(/[[:digit:]]/,"","g",$0)!~gensub(/[[:digit:]]/,"","g",a[FNR]){print $0}
```

Explanation: I harness [`gensub` string function](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) as it does return new string (`gsub` alter selected variable value). I replace `[:digit:]` character using empty string (i.e. delete it) `g`lobally.

Answer (score 0):

Using any awk:

```
compare_files() {
    awk '{key=$0; gsub(/[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?/,0,key)} NR==FNR{a[FNR]=key; next} key!~a[FNR]' "${@}"
}
```

The above doesn't just remove the digits, it replaces every set of numbers, whether they're integers like `17` or decimals like `17.31`,  with the number `0` to avoid false matches.

For example, given input like:

```
file1: foo 1234 bar
file2: foo bar
```

If you just remove the digits then those 2 lines incorrectly become identical:

```
file1: foo bar
file2: foo bar
```

whereas if you replace all numbers with a `0` then they correctly remain different:

```
file1: foo 0 bar
file2: foo bar
```

Note that with the above though we're comparing the lines after converting numbers to 0, we're not modifying the original lines so the output would show the original lines, not the modified ones, for ease of further investigating the differences.